# StackExchange-Driven-Development

Tags: discussion

Is there anything at all that can be done to curb the #lazyweb culture of StackExchange? I'm starting to notice some repeat <strike>offenders</strike> questioners crop up who (quite obviously) are freelancers supporting nearly every site they run by asking questions here.

The questions are broad, from analytics to email delivery issues... and I've become curious if there is a policy surrounding this -- or how we can encourage better behavior, more contribution **back to the community** instead of **constant consumption**.

Now, I'm not an idiot, and I understand that most every person on this site is making a living on Magento somehow. But there are outliers in every community and I'm only asking how we can curtail the rapid-fire question-asking development support for 1 or 2 people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, feel free to flag early & flag often! Also, look at the user history and contact the mods directly (you got my number) to bring special attention. As mods I believe that we can & should kibosh overly-broad/repeat questions. StackExchange's recent update to put questions "on hold" is intended to curb this behavior & introduce users to the SE way of asking/doing things.

Ideally, we can educate as we moderate ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Also questions are a contribution. But if the question is of low quality, downvote, comment, or flag if it is offtopic.

Also keep in mind that there will always more "consumers" than "producers".

I think lots of developers (including myself) are lazy in some way. But this does not excuse ignorance.

So from my point of view it is always okay to ask - but the questions must have a certain quality (especially appreciating comments).

And I refuse to answer any questions as long as the quality is not good and the question is not generally understandable and so useful for this Q&A style page.

Comment: Touché. Questions are contributing. 5 of the same question with increasingly deperate-sounding descriptions like "my client is getting really upset" are not a positive contribution, IMHO.

Comment: Good example. That is SPAM / abuse - sure. I would edit-out this noise. Or downvote/flag to close and ask the OP to edit this out.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that we can post answers with links to resources they can read/should have read about what they want to do.
This way people will be encouraged to post questions and they won't be drawn away.

Then, in time, questions will just be duplicates and can be marked/flagged accordingly.